# InvalidName exception in jacorb

Tags: java, exception, corba, jacorb

I am using Jacorb for corba implementation. I have started the NS on port 900.
When I am trying to start the server I am getting following exception

```
D:\eclipse_workspace\WorkSpace\corba\bin>jaco  hello.MyServer -DORBInitRef.NameService=jacorb::localhost:900
org.jacorb.orb.ORB
Feb 14, 2013 4:00:07 PM org.jacorb.config.JacORBConfiguration <init>
WARNING: no properties found for configuration jacorb
Feb 14, 2013 4:00:07 PM org.jacorb.orb.ORBSingleton <init>
INFO: created ORBSingleton
Exception in thread "main" org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName:    IDL:omg.org/CORBA/ORB/InvalidName:1.0
    at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.resolve_initial_references(ORB.java:1371)
    at hello.MyServer.main(MyServer.java:15)
```

Code is as following

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("ORBInitRef","NameService=jacorb::localhost:900");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass"));
    org.omg.CORBA.ORB orb = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(args, props);

    org.omg.CORBA.Object o = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
    NamingContextExt nc = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow( o );

}
```

Could someone tell whats the problem here?

Comment: I've never seen a corba url with the jacorb prefix before: `-DORBInitRef.NameService=jacorb::localhost:900` have you tried changing it to a corbaloc url: `-DORBInitRef.NameService=corbaloc::localhost:900`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NameService reference has to be either a reference to a file containing an IOR, e.g., `file://tmp/NS_Ref` or an URL, e.g., `http://www.testme.not/NS_Ref` or just a corbaloc/corbaname URL, e.g., `corbaloc:iiop:1.2@host1:3075/NameService`

The last one is most common. You can shorten it, for example, to `corbaloc::localhost:900/NameService`

More information to corbaloc could be found at http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/the-corbaloc-and-corbaname-urls.html