# org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CORBA/ORB/InvalidName:1.0

Tags: java, eclipse, corba, idl, orb

hello i'm trying to create a desktop application using CORBA on eclipse.when i execute the server class main i've getting this errors , although i've imported the APIs of corba and jcorb:

```
INFO Initialising ORB with ID: 
INFO InterceptorManager started with 0 Server Interceptors, 0 Client Interceptors and 1 IOR    Interceptors
INFO oid: 00 01 32 39 36 19 1F 2A 35 10 06 30 46 38 14 14 1B 48 4C 1B ..296..*5..0F8...HL.object is activated
INFO Using server ID (3169780447) for transient POA
org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CORBA/ORB/InvalidName:1.0
at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.resolve_initial_references(ORB.java:1608)
at main.SraCorbaServer.main(SraCorbaServer.java:50)
```

And this is the code of the server class main shown bellow:

```
package main;
import org.omg.CORBA.ORB;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NameComponent;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContext;   
import org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper;

public class SraCorbaServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try {
    /   // Initialisation de l'ORB
        ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);

        // Récupérer la référence du RootPOA et activer le POAManager
        POA rootpoa = (POA) POAHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));
        rootpoa.the_POAManager().activate();

        // Créer un servant (instance de classe d'implémentation) et l'enregistrer avec l'ORB
       SraCorbaImpl sci = new SraCorbaImpl();


        /* *** DEBUT INHERITANCE MODEL (vous pouvez vous référer aux chapitres précédents pour utiliser le modèle Tie Delegation Model) *** */

        // Récupérer une référence du servant
        org.omg.CORBA.Object servantRef = rootpoa.servant_to_reference(sci);

        SraCorba sc = SraCorbaHelper.narrow(servantRef);

        /* *** FIN INHERITANCE MODEL *** */

        // Récupérer la référence du service de nommage
        org.omg.CORBA.Object nsRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
        NamingContextExt nce = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(nsRef);

        // Créer un nom pour le service et ajouter le service
        String serviceName = "NameService";
        NameComponent nc[] = nce.to_name(serviceName);
        nce.rebind(nc, servantRef);

        // Démarrer le service et attendre les requêtes des clients
        System.out.println("On traite les requêtes des clients ...");
        orb.run(); 
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}


}
```

**Thank you for helping me :D **

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872811/invalidname-exception-in-jacorb for a similar question with answer

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyWillemsen but my problem didn't sovle

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
try{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost","localhost");
        props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort","4321");
        ORB orb = ORB.init(args,props);
        SraCorbaImpl od = new SraCorbaImpl();
        POA rootPOA = POAHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));
        byte[] id = rootPOA.activate_object(od);
        org.omg.CORBA.Object ref = rootPOA.id_to_reference(id);
        String ior = orb.object_to_string(ref);
        System.out.println(ior);
        rootPOA.the_POAManager().activate();
        org.omg.CORBA.Object o = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
        NamingContextExt context = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(o);
        NamingContext newContext = context.new_context();
        NameComponent[] ctxName = context.to_name("TEST1");
        try {
            context.bind_context(ctxName,newContext);
        } catch(AlreadyBound e) {
            newContext = NamingContextHelper.narrow(context.resolve(ctxName));
        }
        newContext.rebind(context.to_name("B"),ref);
        System.out.println("Server running !");
        orb.run();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

be careful in this exemple I initialised the port to 4321 so when launching the tnameserv add this option : tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 4321

Comment: Thank you , but the problem didn't solve, i've the same error org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CORBA/ORB/InvalidName:1.0
 at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.resolve_initial_references(ORB.java:1608)
 at main.SraCorbaServer.main(SraCorbaServer.java:98)

Comment: line 98 :  org.omg.CORBA.Object o = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");